# jackson set hint for class properties when converting from Map to POJO

Tags: java, dictionary, mapping, jackson, pojo

Hello I need to convert map to POJO. I Know I can use this code:

```
MyObject obj = (new ObjectMapper()).convertValue(myMap, MyObject.class);
```

But I faced with problem: the keys of map can contain java keywords for example map can be:

```
Map<String, String> map = new Map<String, String>();
map.put("class", "...");
map.put("interface", "...");
map.put("value", "Some value");
```

So after converting I will have initialized value field but I do not know how to assign values with keys "interface" and "class".

```
public class MyObject {
   public String value;
   /*
     I can not define fields named "class" and "inteface" but i need values with this keys
   */
}
```

@JsonProperty annotations do not work for that (and I think the should not work for non JSON convertion).

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why you say `@JsonProperty` doesn't work, the following will bind the map values to POJO

```
public class MyObject {

    @JsonProperty("class")
    private String clazz;
    @JsonProperty("interface")
    private String interfejz;
    @JsonProperty("value")
    private String value;

// setters getters
}
```